# Why am I getting the error `-bash: npm: command not found` (MacOS)?

Tags: bash, npm, nvm

I messed up my  npm configuration by cleaning my machine, and have been having issues with npm on MacOs since.

I tried fully uninstalling and reinstalling npm and nvm, first, but the issue persists.

When I use  `npm -v` or `nvm -v` in bash  terminal I get:

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

and

```
-bash: nvm: command not found
```

So I go try to download nvm with:

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Which  returns:

```
=> nvm is already installed in /Users/user/.nvm, trying to update using git
=> => Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> nvm source string already in /Users/user/.bashrc
=> bash_completion source string already in /Users/user/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Ok, so as instructed I run:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Now npm  and nvm  are accessable in that  instance of the terminal, but in a new  instance I'm back to square one. I thought that this was solved by including the nvm source string in my `.bashrc` but it looks like that is already done.

I have also checked my bash version with

`bash --version`

which returned:

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

How can  I maintain access to `nvm` and `npm` accross bash instances?

Answer (score 2):

Zsh is a very capable shell, although much less popular.

Since `npm` and `nvm` commands are not found, it may be that you did a bit too much cleanup. You'd probably be looking how to reinstall these on MacOS with homebrew. Now I am not sure you will get the installed modules database back.

Comment: Oh cool (I mean, not cool Apple) nice to know that I have outdated Bash that seems potentially insecure, so I just update Bash?

Comment: @QuddusGeorge not sure Bash3.2 has security issues (I don't think), shell is not security focussed anyway. But too often I see posts from MacOS users who discovers that either their obsolete Bash3.2 does not support this or that, or acts funny, or that they have zsh instead like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70748117/7939871

Comment: @QuddusGeorge The first thing to do is to find out what shell you're actually using. `ps $$` will show this (or `echo $SHELL`, but that shows the default for your user account, and that might be overridden). If it's zsh and you're happy with that, just add those commands to `~/.zshrc` instead of (or in addition to) in `~/.bashrc`. (Note: personally, I find bash v3.2 works fine for me -- the features its missing aren't particularly important, it's just a little annoying if you copy some code that assumes they exist.)

Comment: i myself hate Apple in some way but i'd not say Apple "refuse to comply with its GPL3.0". i'd say Apple chose not to ship GPL3 software to avoid violating GPL3.

Comment: @LéaGris I've just checked my  bash version (I updated the question) and it appears to have been up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the exports suggested by the download are not available globally in your bash terminal:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

This means that in theory just by running these exports everytime you need to use npm and nvm this will prove as a temporary solution. Unfortunately, I can tell you the theoretical problem (lack of global knowledge of the path to npm), but I do not actually know how to solve this given the bash terminal is used. Maybe you can continue with some further searching and find a solution with this theory.

Alternatively, a much easier solution is to switch to a Homebrew managed version of Node, which will manage pathing issues for you (allowing global access to npm once again in all terminals by default). This would require [installing Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (make sure to follow instructions carefully once you run the installation command in the bash Terminal) and then the [Node formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node#default):

```
brew install node
```

Keep in mind Homebrew will always install the latest version available (Not LTS).

I have not managed to find a source where the bash terminal is used for node.

If you are not interested in using Homebrew, you can take a look at things I found while trying to help you:

1. [Install using zsh terminal with migration from bash](http://How%20to%20install%20Node.js%20and%20NPM%20with%20MacOS%E2%80%99s%20new%20terminal%20%E2%80%94%20zsh) (if you decide this is the way you want to go)
2. [Node website vs Homebrew vs Using nvm](https://www.newline.co/@Adele/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-on-macos--22782681)